# Sorting on column not working as expected

Tags: sql, sorting, reporting-services, textbox, sql-order-by

I have a report which has parameter for names - forename surname

when all names are selected, it should show values in chart and table accordingly

In my chart, names appear in sorted order but in my table, they don't appear same.

I used 'ORDERBY forename' in my sql query and sorting forename in tablix properties.

```
Query:

SELECT DISTINCT 
Code, Forename, Forename + ' ' + Surname AS Name, Age, Year, Area, Type, StartTime, EndTime
FROM Table
WHERE        (Age IN (@Age)) AND (Type IN (@Type)) AND (Year = @Year)
GROUP BY Code, Forename, Surname, Age, Year, Area, Type, StartTime, EndTime
ORDER BY Forename
```

O/P:

```
Code    Forename   Name   Age   Year    Area    Type    StartTime   EndTime
 SHEEA1 Alyson  Alyson Sheen    1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 09:00    1899-12-30 10:30
 SHEEA1 Alyson  Alyson Sheen    1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 13:15    1899-12-30 14:45
 SHEEA1 Alyson  Alyson Sheen    1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 15:00    1899-12-30 16:30
 DIXOD1 Daniel  Daniel Dixon    1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 10:45    1899-12-30 12:15
 DIXOD1 Daniel  Daniel Dixon    1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 13:15    1899-12-30 14:45
 KAYEJ1 Jemma   Jemma Kaye  1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 09:00    1899-12-30 10:30
 AMOOJ1 Josephine   Josephine Amoo  1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 15:15    1899-12-30 16:45
 AMOOJ1 Josephine   Josephine Amoo  1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 13:30    1899-12-30 15:00
 LEEK2  Katy    Katy Lee    1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 09:00    1899-12-30 10:30
 LEEK2  Katy    Katy Lee    1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 11:00    1899-12-30 12:30
 LEEK2  Katy    Katy Lee    1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 13:30    1899-12-30 15:00
 NSUBL1 Lawrence    Lawrence Nsubuga    1416    2015 Eng+Maths GCSE 1899-12-30 13:15    1899-12-30 15:00
 NSUBL1 Lawrence    Lawrence Nsubuga    1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 09:00    1899-12-30 10:30
 NSUBL1 Lawrence    Lawrence Nsubuga    1416    2015 Eng+Maths  GCSE    1899-12-30 15:00    1899-12-30 16:30
 GOODN1 Nicola  Nicola Goodman  1416    2015    Eng+Maths   GCSE    1899-12-30 09:00    1899-12-30 10:30
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: which table are you refering to. the SQL table, or the table onscreen?

Comment: @takarii - in my report tablix

Comment: Can you show your code, seems like you might have a mistake

Comment: @Takarii - Please see above

Comment: query looks fine to me, so that suggests its to do with how you are binding things in your code. can you expand, and include the language you are using?

Comment: can you show me what your actual output is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Row Groups of a tablix have their own separate set of Sorting properties, which are prioritised over the sorting properties of the overall tablix. Right-click on a Row Group to open it's Properties, and check the Sorting options.

If you created a row group in your tablix on your people's Code values, the Code column will be the default sort for that group. By changing the properties of the group, you can still group by the code but order by the forename.

[image: Group Sorting Properties screenshot]